# How to get a single value using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i need to get `service_price` field from db by using this code.

```
public function get_service_price($id) { 
 $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('service');
    return $query->row('service_price');  
}
```

here i called this function function.

```
 public function vat($vat=14.5)

 {
  $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
  $data['service_price'] = $this->service_model->get_service_price($id);
  $price_with_vat=0;
  $price_with_vat = $data + ($vat*($data/100));
  //$price_with_vat=78.005;
  $price_with_vat = round($price_with_vat, 2);
  $this->load->view('admin/service/vat', $price_with_vat);
  }
```

There some mistake. please kindly help me

Comment: Can you share the errors you got?

Comment: what's the error you got?

Comment: Why don't you use limit if you really want to get single value only

Comment: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\application\controllers\admin_service.php on line 282 this is my error

Answer (score 0):

To get first row use following

```
$query = $this->db
->where('id', $id);
->get('service');
$firstRow = $query->first_row();
return $firstRow->service_price;
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: controllers/admin_service.php
Line Number: 280 this is my error

Comment: What is at line no 280 ?

Comment: $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
 line number 280:print_r($data['service_price']); 
                            die();

Comment: make sure you load `$this->load->library('uri');`

Comment: where should i add this  snippet

Comment: At first line of your function.

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
public function get_service_price($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM service WHERE id='$id'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

in controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$data['service_price'] = $this->service_model->get_service_price($id);
$price_with_vat=0;
$price_with_vat = $data[0]['table_field_name'] + ($vat*($data[0]['table_field_name']/100)); //$price_with_vat=78.005;
$price_with_vat = round($price_with_vat, 2);
$this->load->view('admin/service/vat', $price_with_vat);
```

in view

```
foreach ($service_price as $new_service_price)
{
    echo $new_service_price['table_field_name'];//exapmle echo $new_service_price['service_price']
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. but i am getting this error.Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\application\controllers\admin_service.php on line 282

Comment: line number 282:  $price_with_vat = $data + ($vat*($data/100)); //$price_with_vat=78.005;

Comment: `$data` why you using this veritable??

Comment: $data['service_price'] = $this->service_model->get_service_price($id); in this line i am getting that service price

Comment: use this `$data[0]['table_field_name']` instead of `$data`

Comment: no i am getting the same error.Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\xampp\htdocs\elfanto\elfanto_billing\application\controllers\admin_service.php on line 282

Comment: before 282 write `print_r($data['service_price']); die();`

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
this is my error.
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: controllers/admin_service.php
Line Number: 280

Comment: after this line `$data['service_price'] = $this->service_model->get_service_price($id);` add this `print_r($data['service_price']); die();`

Comment: no its should work. Your line is in some other place

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your model :

```
  public function get_service_price($id) { 
    $this->db->select('service_price');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();  
 }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: controllers/admin_service.php
Line Number: 280 this is my error